# FPDP useTemplate does not copy the buttons (forms)

Tags: fpdf

I am using the useTemplate method of FPDF to create a PDF with lesser pages than the original file. Each page has 4 Form field buttons but these buttons are not copied over to the new PDF file.

Is this achievable with FPDF?

Kind regards,

Baran

Comment: No, [FPDI](https://setasign.com/fpdi) does not support annotations as they are not part of a pages content stream. What do you want to do with the imported PDF exactly?

Comment: Each page consists of 4 annotations and each annotation is a link to one of the 4 pages. By pressing on the button the user will be navigated to that specific page

Comment: This doesn't answer why you import the pages. What do you do with FPDI?